# Cannot implicitly convert type to System.Net.Authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am adding a .cs (Class) file and using a Web Reference in it:

`using ServiceMemberIDSS;`

When I type in the following code, I get on the return value of _authHeader:

```
private Authorization IDSSCredentials()
{
    ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader _authHeader = new AuthorizeHeader();
    _authHeader.UserName = "theUserName";
    _authHeader.Password = "thePassword";
    return _authHeader;
}
```

The `_authHeader` tag at the end where it is being returned at is underlined in red and says this when I hover over it:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader' to 'System.Net.Authorization'`

How can this be fixed?  I need to send the Username and Password to the service before it will give a response.

AuthorizeHeader is defined in the `Members.wsdl` file within the `App_WebReferences` folder as XML, as follows:

```
<s:element name="AuthorizeHeader" type="tns:AuthorizeHeader" />
  <s:complexType name="AuthorizeHeader">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
    <s:anyAttribute />
  </s:complexType>
```

Comment: `ServiceMemberIDSS` is a Web Reference (.asmx?wsdl).  Is is located in the `App_WebReferences` folder of the root of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just qualify the return type and the `new()` with the namespace. Like so.

```
private ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader IDSSCredentials()

    ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader _authHeader = new ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader();

    _authHeader.UserName = "theUserName";
    _authHeader.Password = "thePassword";
    return _authHeader;
}
```

Comment: This does not help, still says the same, where `return _authHeader` is located.

Comment: What is the type of `AuthorizeHeader` in your `ServiceMemberIDSS` class? How is it defined?

Comment: Ok, updated question with the XML that loads this in the `members.wsdl` file, if that helps any.

Comment: HA, I'm an idiot:  `private AuthorizeHeader IDSSCredentials()` that fixes it.